# Build a slider based on the data returned from API call

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, api

Need to build a slider (carousel) which should be based on the data returned from the API call. There are 3 values which I need to pull. `image`, `title` and `description`.

It must be a `picture`, `heading`, and `description` (on each slide, pulled from JSON).

jQuery

```
var myJSON = 'apiCall';
$.getJSON('myJSON, { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        $('body').append($('<img>', {  
        }));
    });
});
```

HTML

```
   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
             <ol class="carousel-indicators">
               <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-80" src="..." alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h5></h5>
         <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-80" src="..." alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h5></h5>
         <p></p>
        </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-80" src="..." alt="Third slide">
       <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h5></h5>
         <p></p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Describe what you mean when you say *had a problem with pushing the data to the slider*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.get('apiCall')
      .then(function(response) {
          var $carousel = $('#carouselExampleIndicators');
          var $carouselInner = $carousel.find('.carousel-inner');

          response.data.forEach(function(item, i) {
            var template = '';

            if(i === 0) {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item active">';
            } else {
              template = '<div class="carousel-item">';
            }
            
            template += '<img class="d-block w-80" src="' + item.image + '" alt="Second slide">'; 
            template += '<div class="carousel-caption">';
            template += '<h5>' + item.title_a + '</h5>';
            template += '<p>' + item.category + '</p>';
            template += '</div>';
            template += '</div>';

            $carouselInner.append(template);
          })

          $carousel.carousel();
      })
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>
```

Hey, here is the example with jQuery and ES5 js. I suggest you using https://handlebarsjs.com/ for templating html. It will look nicer.

Comment: Thank you, I see that it is working, but when I added to my code, it doesn't. I linked the json, maybe it is about the json structure?

Comment: Yes, you need to adapt the template for json properties. I edited the code above (I added json you provide), so you can try now.

Comment: I see it is work now. Thank you! Could you tell me please, why do you think I have this bug in my console? "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" and "$.get is not a function"
I have all libraries (jQuery and Bootstrap) linked.

Comment: jQuery library is not properly included. Check the order of included scripts. Your javascript must be included below the jQuery and Bootstrap script.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to help you with implementing that. I think I helped you more than enough with the provided example.

Answer (score 0):

```
let html = `
<div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-80" src="${imgSrc}" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
         <h5>${title}</h5>
         <p>${parangraph}</p>
        </div>
  </div>
`
$(".carousel-inner")[0].append(html)
```

Put the above code in a loop, and you should be all set.
The imgSrc, title and parangraph should be dynamically generated from your API calls.